# XSLT choose to apply the filter

Tags: xslt

I have the following question:

This i want to use in choose:

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Table/Rows/Row" />
```

I tried:

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$paramId">
            <xsl:copy-of select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@ID=$paramId]" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

But it didnt work, anyone has any idea?

Just to clarify, based on the paramId if it is empty then i should get all the rows, but if the paramId is not empty i would like to apply filter ID=paramId, how can i do this?

Comment: can you elaborate your question

Comment: i've updated the post with more explaration: basically based on the paramId i would apply or not apply the filter on the set of rows.

Comment: Can you show your input XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how you declare and initialize the parameter or variable you have, and you don't show that part of your code.

Assuming you have

```
<xsl:param name="paramId" select="/.."/>
```

I would then simply do

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[not($paramId) or @ID = $paramId]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have paramId declared as

```
<xsl:param name="paramId" select="''" />
```

I would use it in `test` attribute of xsl:when in this way

```
<xsl:when test="$paramId = ''">
```